# What would be the steps to implementing a formatter for your programming language?

Tags: tokens

Right now, I am using ClangFormat to format code written in my programming language, but that's not ideal, among other things, because [ClangFormat treats `:=` (assignment) as two different tokens](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1695/330). So, how would I go about implementing the formatter for my programming language?

It seems to me that I cannot reuse the code from the tokenizer of my programming language, because [the tokenizer for my programming language](https://sourceforge.net/p/aecforwebassembly/code/ci/master/tree/tokenizer.cpp) deletes the comments, and I don't want to delete the comments from the code I am formatting. But don't I need to somehow parse the code I am formatting, to know how many tabs/spaces I should put before some token? How am I supposed to parse a code with comments in it?